# Code that replaces words with different characters

Tags: c++, string

the purpose of this code is to replace words that have 1 character with "|", words with 2 characters with "||", and words with 3 characters with "---".
Every time I run it it gives me an error:

> string subscript out of range

Any idea what could be causing it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string text;
    int x, i, count=0;
    cout << "Enter the string of text you wish to modify" << endl << "(Make sure to inlude a period at the end of the text)" << endl;
    getline(cin, text);
    x = text.length();
    cout << x;
        if (text[x - 1] == '.')
        {
            for (i = 0; i <= x; i++)
            {
                count++;
                if (text[i] == ' ')
                {
                    if (count == 1)
                    {
                        text[i - 1] = '|';
                        count = 0;
                    }
                    else if (count == 2)
                    {
                        text[i - 2] = '|';
                        text[i - 1] = '|';
                        count = 0;
                    }
                    else if (count == 3)
                    {
                        text[i - 3] = '-';
                        text[i - 2] = '-';
                        text[i - 1] = '-';
                        count = 0;
                    }
                    else if (count > 4)
                    {
                        count = 0;
                    }
                }
                if (text[i] = '.')
                {
                    if (count == 1)
                    {
                        text[i - 1] = '|';
                    }
                    else if (count == 2)
                    {
                        text[i - 2] = '|';
                        text[i - 1] = '|';
                    }
                    else if (count == 3)
                    {
                        text[i - 3] = '-';
                        text[i - 2] = '-';
                        text[i - 1] = '-';
                    }
                }
            }
            cout << "Here is your modified sentence" << endl << text;
        }
    else
    {
        cout << "Your statement does not end in a period, goodbye" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for (i = 0; i <= x; i++)` this should be `for (i = 0; i < x; i++)`

Comment: On the first iteration, i==0 and count==1, but then you write to `text[i-1]`, that's not going to work. Same on the next iterations, i is off by 1.

Comment: @tux3 count is 0 when i is 0

Comment: @Lashane unless I'm missing something, that count++ just before the if is going to ensure count > i.

Comment: @tux3 you're right, I've missed that, but as soon as first symbol is not space or dot - it is ok, of course whole algorithm is wrong because of such errors

Answer (score 3):

"subscript out of range" means you are indexing an array with a bad index.

try

```
 for(i=0;i<x;i++)
```

or you can use a switch statement with text.length().

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson5.html